# Should [oneplus], [oneplusone], [oneplustwo] and [oneplusthree] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

While reviewing [this tag description change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14638636), I became suspicious that it might not be an appropriate tag for SO, perhaps even spam. The description is given as:

> The OnePlus One is the first smartphone developed by new start-up
>   company OnePlus

Furthermore, there seem to be a range of related tags: [oneplusone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oneplusone), [oneplustwo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oneplustwo), [oneplusthree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oneplusthree) that are decreasingly popular. I think they should be merged, and link to the underlying programming technology rather than the hardware - perhaps OxygenOS.

Comment: I think some of the questions benefit from knowning the device model. But I guess that is not a thing for keywords, and actually having a single tagfor the whole hardware family is enough (+ actual OS or OS Dialect tag - android or oxygenos).

Comment: One should also note that all tag-wiki entries (the suggested as well as the accepted ones) are all plagiarized from external sources....

Answer (score 3):

I would rather *one minus* (read burninate; couldn't think of a better pun :D) all such tags as they are off-topic as far as Stack Overflow is concerned.

The underlying OS (Oxygen OS in this case) can be used as a tag in case a question is related. Moreover, general OS level tags (like Android, iOS, etc.) already exist.

Comment: The *tag* isn't off-topic. Rather, certain *questions* that might have that tag applied are off-topic. In particular, questions *about the phone hardware that have nothing to do with programming*. Those would be off-topic for the [tag:iphone] tag, too. But there certainly are programming questions that are on-topic for [tag:iphone], and presumably there would be for the [tag:oneplusone] tag, too.

Answer (score 1):

Some programming problems are specific to a device. That's why we have, e.g. the [nexus-6p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nexus-6p) tag and the [iphone-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6) tag. These tags are needed if a problem is dependent on the device. Now, they're of course misused, as is every tag (think [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio), [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)). But that's not a reason for removing these tags; that's a reason to cleanup the tag and remove improperly tagged questions. A problem could only manifest on one of these devices, so saying "all devices in this family" are the same doesn't work.